# Gif is not working with word vsto addin

Tags: vsto, office-addins, word-addins, officedev

I am working on application made with VSTO Addin.I am trying to add a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton` on Word Ribbon, with its image property set to a gif file present in my project resources, but when i try to run addin the gif I added is not animating. Gif used is a spinner. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that the Office Ribbon interface does not support animated GIF format...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information.